# Unable to import Keras(from TensorFlow 2.0) in PyCharm 2019.2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pycharm, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have just installed the stable version of TensorFlow 2.0 (released on October 1st 2019) in PyCharm.

**The problem** is that the **keras package is unavailable**.
 [image: Unable to import keras]

The actual error is :

> "**cannot import name 'keras' from tensorflow**"

I have installed via `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0` the `CPU version`, and then uninstalled the CPU version and installed the GPU version , via `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.`

Neither of the above worked versions of TensorFlow were working properly(could not import keras or other packages via `from tensorflow.package_X import Y`).

If I **revert TensorFlow to version 2.0.0.b1**, **keras is available** as a package (PyCharm recognises it) and everything runs smoothly.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Am I making a mistake in the installation process?

UPDATE --- Importing from the Python Console works and allows the imports without any error.
[image: Writing from the console works]

Comment: I installed today and it is working fine i used    pip install tensorflow-gpu   .

Comment: Instead of providing some screenshot that doesn't really show anything, you should provide an actual piece of code that fails and displays the problem. You might just be importing things the wrong way.

Comment: The screenshot is meant to demonstrate that PyCharm is unable to even see keras package within TensorFlow. The error is  'cannot import keras from tensorflow --- Unable to find module keras'

Comment: It seems to be an error of PyCharm IDE, as far as I read on separate issues opened on GitHub and on PyCharm : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002486739-PyCharm-cannot-import-tensorflow-keras

Comment: @xdurch0 I have added photos both in the question and in the solution provided. I hope it is clearer now (Danke fur die Uberwachung)

Comment: +explanations with regard to the error.

Comment: Ok, sorry for maybe coming across a little rude, I just really didn't understand what the issue was. Glad you were able to (more or less) solve it.

Comment: Yes, no problem, it is good that a number of solutions appeared. If you were among those who voted to close the question, I would kindly ask you to unvote the closing as it may very well help other people, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**For PyCharm Users**

For those who use PyCharm. Install future (EAP) release `2019.3 EAP build 193.3793.14` from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/). With that, you will be able to use autocomplete for the current stable release of TensorFlow (i.e. 2.0). I have tried it and it works :).

**For other IDEs**

For users with other IDEs, this will be resolved only after the stable version is released, which is anyways the case now. But this might take some more time for a fix. See the comment [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31973#issuecomment-524928419). I assume it will be wise to wait and keep using `version 2.0.0.b1`. On the other hand avoid imports from `tensorflow_core` if you do not want to refactor your code in the future.

**Note:** for autocomplete to work use import statement as below

```py
import tensorflow.keras as tk

# this does not work for autocomplete 
# from tensorflow import keras as tk
```

The autocomplete works for TensorFlow 2.0.0 on CPU version, but the autocomplete does not work for the GPU version.

Comment: Yes, I would also wait until PyCharm fixes this issue. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED --- See the answers to this problem below.

**SOLUTION 1 (best solution)**

Is the accepted answer provided above. It works on EAP version, I tested it on several machines with Windows.

**SOLUTION 2**

Although PyCharm does not recognise the modules, running the .py file works. I still do not know if this is a problem of TensorFlow or PyCharm, but this is the solution that I have found, many people have run into this problem.

[image: PyCharm does not see the imports, considers them error]

[image]

**SOLUTION 3**

Import the modules from `tensorflow_core` instead of `tensorflow`

Example: `from tensorflow_core.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator`

However, as mentioned by @Nagabhushan S N in the comment below and above in the accepted answer:

> On the other hand avoid imports from tensorflow_core if you do not
>   want to refactor your code in the future.

[image]

Comment: The answer was indeed edited, in the sense that I explicitly stated that the best solution is added above.

Comment: Okay sorry. My bad. If you can make a minor change, I'll remove the downvote

Comment: No problem, good that we are on the same wavelength now(I will edit it now)

Comment: Also, as mentioned in Praveen Kulkarni's answer, I suggest you add the below warning for the 3rd solution: `On the other hand avoid imports from tensorflow_core if you do not want to refactor your code in the future.` You can provide a link to his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58192020/3337089