# Why does PyCharm not realize that tf.keras is installed?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, pycharm

Although tensorflow is installed, Pycharm does not realize that the module tf.keras exists.
Hovering over the keras results in the following text showing up: "Cannot find reference "keras" in '__init__.py'"

Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using PyCharm version lower than 3.0.

TensorFlow 2.0 is not running on PyCharm versions older than 2019.3 version.

You can find the answer to your question here: [Unable to import Keras(from TensorFlow 2.0) in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188704/unable-to-import-kerasfrom-tensorflow-2-0-in-pycharm)

Comment: Thank you. Updating the IDE solved the problem. Question is indeed duplicate, therfore I'll delete it soon. Nevertheless thanks a lot!

Comment: No need to delete it, people will close it as duplicate. If you do delete it, please upvote the original question so that more people can see&solve their problems! Thank you.