# tensorflow backend error. AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I'm using Version: 2.1.0 of TensorFlow and 2.3.1 of keras. While importing any module of keras i'm facing below tensorflow back-end error.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, os, re, json, math, time 
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense 
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score 
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-82-2f712055860b> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd, numpy as np, os, re, json, math, time
----> 2 from keras.models import Sequential
      3 from keras.layers import Dense
      4 from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
      5 from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 from . import losses_utils
      8 from . import metrics_utils

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in <module>
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .load_backend import epsilon
      2 from .load_backend import set_epsilon
      3 from .load_backend import floatx
      4 from .load_backend import set_floatx
      5 from .load_backend import cast_to_floatx

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py in <module>
     88 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     89     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 90     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     91 else:
     92     # Try and load external backend.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in <module>
     54 get_graph = tf_keras_backend.get_graph
     55 # learning_phase_scope = tf_keras_backend.learning_phase_scope  # TODO
---> 56 name_scope = tf.name_scope
     57 
     58 

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope'
```

Looking forward to quick solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you switch to using the `keras` module inside TensorFlow.

It is better maintained and you will not have incompatibility issues.

According to Francois Chollet:

> Keras version 2.3.0 is here, and it is the last major multi-backend
>   release. Going forward, users are recommended to switch their code
>   over to tf.keras in TensorFlow 2.0. This release brings API changes
>   and a few breaking changes. Have a look under the hood and see what it
>   includes, as well as what the plans are going forward.

Switching all the imports instead of

```
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

will solve all your incompatibility issues.

You can uninstall Keras altogether as a separate package since it is already included by default in TensorFlow.

OBSERVATION: If PyCharm does not recognise `tensorflow.keras`, you will need to update PyCharm to the latest version >=2019.3. Only starting with that version is TensorFlow 2.0 recognised accordingly in PyCharm. Please consult the answer below for more information:

[Unable to import Keras(from TensorFlow 2.0) in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188704/unable-to-import-kerasfrom-tensorflow-2-0-in-pycharm)

Comment: hey, thanks for quick response. Now, it's throwing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.models'; 'tensorflow.keras' is not a package

Comment: It is because you are using an old version of PyCharm which does not recognise the tensorflow.keras module. You will need to update PyCharm to 2019.3 version in order for it to recognise it.

Comment: I'm using Jupyter notebook not Pycharm.

Comment: What Python version are you using? It may be also due to the fact that sys.path does not have the necessary paths.

Comment: it is Python 3.7.4

Comment: Can you please uninstall everything and reinstall(ensure that the Kernel is restored always after installing and uninstalling). This is now not a problem of code in itself but of module not recognising the path to the installation folders.

Comment: ok. 

My system path variable:
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\Library\bin\graphviz\;C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts;




I had made some changes in my PATH variable just few minutes ago. Do you think i need to restart my system to make them effective?

Comment: At least restarting the kernel so that it sees the new updated paths; but for certainty, restart the computer. We will see how to solve this if the problem still persists.

Comment: I just restarted my system and when i opened anaconda promt it showed up like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cgVVtH0lVbRMZPK6rgPORy9sjVcga9QI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Although after restarting the system. the issue is solved. thanks.

Comment: hey, @Timbus can you think of any solution to the issue which i mentioned about Anaconda promt? 
Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cgVVtH0lVbRMZPK6rgPORy9sjVcga9QI/view

Comment: Sorry, did not work with VS. Also, if you have any other question, please ask it it another separate question.