# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope' when import keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying import keras in jupyter notebook

```
import keras
```

which raises the following error:

[image]
How can I solve this problem??

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724309/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-name-scope-with-keras... Also maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711670/tensorflow-backend-error-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute

Comment: Which version of Tensorflow and Keras are you using?

Comment: I using 2.0.0 Tensorflow and 2.3.1 Keras

Comment: Please can you try ```pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==2.0.0```